# Salesforce dx: how to get the diff between server and local file

Tags: salesforcedx

I searched through the dx cli reference but didn't see a diff command. So if the server and local version have conflicts, how do you usually find the diff and merge those files?

Comment: So, I see where you can *see* the differences, but not compare them. Sad story. Hopefully someone's got an answer short of manual.

Comment: @sfdcfox Is there a command or approach to retrieve the server version without having to go to developer console? So in that way we can use a third party diff tool to compare which is also acceptable solution

Comment: So, I *think* I got this figured out, but I'd definitely clone and try it locally first before committing to this course of action (errr, no pun intended?). Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the solution. This definitely works and is probably the best solution currently. However, I still think sfdx should provide a diff here to avoid using this tricky approach.

Comment: I agree with that. Perhaps an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) is in order? I'll see if I can get the attention of the DX team to see if that's something they might do in the future.

Comment: @sfdcfox I will try to think about whether I can write a canned solution for this without using git. Basically I can copy the conflicted files into a conflict folder and make two versions: project and org. Then compare them with a third party tool... Shouldn't be hard though

Comment: That's the non-git way I was going to suggest, but it sounds basically as manual as you can get. At least with git, you end up with just a flag of differences, such as from git status. Still, I think you could use winmerge or whatever the diff tool of choice is with two project folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized that the most sensible course of action would be to use git for this purpose. This solution assumes that you use git to manage your code (you *are* using git, aren't you?):

```
git checkout -b conflicts
sfdx force:source:pull --forceoverwrite
git commit -am "source conflicts"
git checkout feature-branch
git diff feature-branch conflicts
```

This should show you all of the changes that occurred. You could also further do:

```
git merge conflicts
```

Which will leave you in git's merging mode, and you can then check the conflicts and resolve them manually. Once done, you can then do:

```
sfdx force:source:push --forceoverwrite
```

Answer (score 5):

If you've done work locally and wish to see a summary of that work. Or vice-versa you've done something in the org, and want to know what changes were made at a high level, you can simply use:

```
sfdx force:source:status
```

This will probably be the fastest way to walk away with an overview. You can then decide whether to drill into more detail.

```
$ sfdx force:source:status
=== Source Status
STATE           FULL NAME                                                                 TYPE                  PROJECT PATH
──────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Local Changed   PropertyListDaysOnMarketChart/PropertyListDaysOnMarketChartController.js  AuraDefinitionBundle  force-app/main/default/aura/PropertyListDaysOnMarketChart/PropertyListDaysOnMarketChartController.js
Local Add       PropertyTrigger                                                           ApexTrigger           force-app/main/default/triggers/PropertyTrigger.trigger
Local Add       PropertyTrigger                                                           ApexTrigger           force-app/main/default/triggers/PropertyTrigger.trigger-meta.xml
Remote Add      Property__c.Last_Sold_Price__c                                            CustomField
Remote Add      Admin                                                                     Profile
Remote Add      Custom: Sales Profile                                                     Profile
Remote Add      Custom: Marketing Profile                                                 Profile
Remote Add      Custom: Support Profile                                                   Profile
Remote Changed  Property__c-Property Layout                                               Layout                force-app/main/default/layouts/Property__c-Property Layout.layout-meta.xml
```

Early on the Salesforce DX product team signaled that creating an org-to-local-source diff tool was a low priority. The vision here is that if your source of truth is your VCS, and your scratch org is only a temporary development environment, then better to use the excellent diff tools that already exist and do all diffs locally. There was also significant effort spent early on in Salesforce DX to make the MD API more predictable so that diff tools *could* be used effectively.